# Create Folder On Server Upon Registration

Tags: php, registration

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I've been trying to find a tutorial or examples of how to automatically create a folder in my server upon 'user registration', to be more specific:

The top level folder to be called the 'username' that the user registered with, the next level folder within this to be called 'images', and the folder within that, to be called 'thumbs'.

As I said I've been searching for something that can show me how to do this, and I've not had any luck.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps guide me to some tutorial or example that I could use to help me achieve this. Ideally, it would be great if I could get this into a PHP script which could be run automatically when the user completes registration.

Many thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically making use of [`mkdir`](http://php.net/mkdir), however you might want to wrap this into a class of it's own so you can later on better bind it to a user-name or ID to move away from concrete pathnames:

```
$userDir = new UserDir($pathToUserDir);
$userDir->createImageDirectory();

class UserDir extends SplFileInfo
{
    public function createThumbDirectory()
    {
        return $this->createSubdirectory('thumb');
    }
    public function createImageDirectory()
    {
        return $this->createSubdirectory('image');
    }
    private function createSubdirectory($name)
    {
        $path = $this->getPathname();
        $dir = $path . PATH_SEPARATOR . $name;
        return mkdir($dir);
    }
}
```

You can then extend this with error condition checking in a central place, so it's easy to use in your application.

Comment: Hi, this is great, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post and the suggested code. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

use mkdir. 
source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php
complete description given

Comment: All, many thanks for your help on this. You've all given a really good starting point. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

To create folders with php you can use the function `mkdir` (which stands for "make directory").

http://php.net/manual/de/function.mkdir.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like exec() to run a system command like mkdir http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php