# unlink files with a case-insensitive (glob-like) pattern

Tags: php, directory, glob

I have two folders, in one i have the videos and in the second one the configuration files for each video(3 files per video). Now if i want to delete a video i have to delete files by hand.
I found this :

```
<?php

$filename = 'name.of.the.video.xml';       
$term = str_replace(".xml","", $filename);
$dirPath = ("D:/test/");

foreach (glob($dirPath.$term.".*") as $removeFile)
{
    unlink ($removeFile);
}

?>
```

A echo will return:

D:/test/name.of.the.video.jpg

D:/test/name.of.the.video.srt

D:/test/name.of.the.video.xml

Is ok and it help me a lot, but i have a problem here.

Not all files are the same ex:
Name.of.The.video.jpg
Name.Of.The.Video.xml

If i echo the folder looking for that string and is not identic with the $filename will return empty.
So, my question is, how can i make that search Case insensitive?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making use of the [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) function which is case sensitive. You are using the wrong function therefore to get the list of files.

You should therefore first normalize the filenames in the directory so they all share the same case (e.g. all lowercase). Or you need to use another method to get the directory listing case-insensitive. I suggest the first, however if that is not an option, why don't you `glob` for all files first and then filter the list of files using [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) which allows to specify patterns that are case-insensitive?

Which leads me to the point that it's more practicable to use [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/DirectoryIterator) with a [`RegexIterator`](http://php.net/RegexIterator):

```
$filename = 'name.of.the.video.xml';
$term = basename($filename, ".xml");
$files = new DirectoryIterator($dirPath);
$filesFiltered = new RegexIterator($files, sprintf('(^%s\\..*$)i', preg_quote($term)));
foreach($filesFiltered as $file)
{
    printf("delete: %s\n", $file);
    unlink($file->getPathname());
}
```

A good example of the flexibility of the `Iterator`s code are your changed requirements: Do that for two directories at once. You just create two `DirectoryIterator`s and append the one to the other with an [`AppendIterator`](http://php.net/AppendIterator). Job done. The rest of the code stays the same:

```
...
$files = new AppendIterator();
$files->append(new DirectoryIterator($dirPath1));
$files->append(new DirectoryIterator($dirPath2));
...
```

Voilá. Sounds good? `glob` is okay for some quick jobs that need just it. For everything else with directory operations start to consider the SPL. It has much more power.

Comment: $removeFile = scandir($dirPath);

print_r(preg_grep("/$term/i",$removeFile));

I will try with this

Comment: @akun: I added you an example, not that you misunderstood what I meant. It's about deleting files, so take care.

Comment: @akun: Better take `DirectoryIterator`.

Comment: `code` $filename = 'name.of.the.video.xml';

 $term = str_replace(".xml","", $filename);
   $dirPath = ("D:/test/");

     $removeFile = scandir($dirPath);

     $test = (preg_grep("/$term/i",$removeFile));
          foreach ($test as $value) {
      unlink ($dirPath.$value);
   
    }

Comment: @akun: Better take the iterator example from the answer. You need to quote the term for example to make the regex pattern work correctly. Also you have a [`SPLFileInfo`](http://php.net/SPLFileInfo) object instead of just a string which is very useful.

Comment: Warning: unlink(D:/test) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in C:\www\php\ip.php on line 76, with your first version was fine

Comment: May fault, it's `$file->getPathname()` instead of `->getPath()` (which is the directory only). See as well the [`SPLFileInfo`](http://php.net/SPLFileInfo) documentation.

Comment: Perfect, and now before we close the topic, is there a way $dirpath to be 2 separate folders? i talk about the other folder where i keep the videos(same name just the extension is .mov).

Comment: Yes that's especially easy with `Iterators`. You create two `DirectoryIterators` and append the one with the other with an [`AppendIterator`](http://php.net/AppendIterator). Job done. The rest of the code stays the same.

Comment: sorry , but this script will delete "name.of.the.video.xml" and "name.of.the.video.part.1.xml" or "name.of.the.video.1.xml" and that's not good at all.

Comment: You have not specified which file extensions should be allowed. If you need to match the last dot, the regular expression must be changed (inside the sprintf), e.g. for three character extensions (a-z, no numbers, no dots): `(^%s\\.[a-z]{3}$)i` - that's just the regex pattern (like with glob).

Comment: the extensions can be, srt, xml,mov,jpg. I changed the code and i think is working

Comment: You might find this answer useful, too: [Create Folder On Server Upon Registration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8646173/367456) - the topic differs a bit, but I link it because it shows that it can make sense you wrap your "video delete" operation into a class of it's own which does the video related file-operations.

Answer (score 1):

Is strcasecmp() a valid function for this? Its a case insensitive str comparison function?

Surely if you know the file name and you can echo it out, you can pass this to unlink()?