# Am I using move_uploaded_file() correctly to add images to dynamic location?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have received some errors when I tried using the function:

> move_upload_file()

.
I have tried researching it, but I can't find any solution.
The error code I receive is the following:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(example.com/users/**username goes here**/test.png):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in members.php on
>   line 53
>
> **AND**
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpW2QDD0'
>   to 'example.com/users/**username goes here**/test.png' in members.php on line 53

What I wish to do is make the image being uploaded to the folder, into a folder inside of the folder **users**. I want the folder to have the same name as the username of the person uploading the photo.

This is the PHP of the image uploader:

```
if (isset($_POST['profilepicture']))
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        if (file_exists("example.com/users/$username/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"example.com/users/$username/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        }
    }
}
```

AND this is the upload image form:

```
<form action='members.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<label for="file">Profile Picture</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="profilepicture" value="Upload">

</form>
```

Why am I getting these errors? and does this function create a new folder if the user does not allready have a folder in the website folder?

***I am grateful for any help, thank you!***

Comment: `example.com/users/...` is very likely wrong. Use the absolute, filesystem path to make sure you're specifying the right location

Comment: so should I use /users/$username? so that it creates a new folder if there is no existing?

Comment: If the directory doesn't yet exist, you need to first create it using ´mkdir()`. Re what path you should use, your admin should be able to tell you the correct absolute filesystem path

Comment: Yupp, I am testing out now, thank you @Pekka웃!

Comment: You are just seeing an error message. Understand it. Fix it. Done. See as well: [Create Folder On Server Upon Registration](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8646073/367456)

Comment: Also please see: [PHP: How to check if file not exists or permission is denied?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9649770/367456)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new directory if not exist. And then move that file to that folder.

```
if (!file_exists('example.com/users/'.$username)) {
    mkdir('example.com/users/'.$username);
}
```

Your code must be like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['profilepicture']))
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        if (file_exists("example.com/users/".$username . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
          if (!file_exists('example.com/users/'.$username)) 
          {
              mkdir('example.com/users/'.$username);
          }
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"example.com/users/$username/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you recommand using URL or the destination in the folder?

Comment: The best way to store users file is not like this...:) you have to store file address in Database.(so you dont have to create many directory in server..:)

Comment: I would recommend using the absolute path in the folder. Because it's the only way that works.

Comment: @Pekka웃 You mean get file url like this?? dirname(__FILE__)

Comment: @Fasilkk, do you have any link or searchword that I can use to look up how to do this?

Comment: @friedBitz Do you want to keep users file url in database(better than this way)?

Comment: Hmmm, yes, if this can be applied to the same table as the login details, that would be great (if this is secure).

Comment: for that one you have to create a field to store url in you database. store image urllink to database. and call when ever you want.:)

Comment: Okai, so all the images should be stored under the same folder in the public folder then?

Comment: yes.. no problem. you can do so..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31992/discussion-between-fasil-kk-and-friedbitz)

Answer (score 1):

Recheck your code to see you are creating a directory using variable $username

Comment: Please put this as a comment instead of an answer, as you do not come with any solution to fix the problem.

Comment: @FriedBitz: It's your job to tell if this fixes your problem or not. However, while we're at it: You are totally right that *any* answer for a *too localtized* question like yours is merely a comment - you have spared the trouble-shooting so far so anything is of commenting nature. When you're lucky somebody hits the nail and you will accept it as an answer later - however this is unacceptable on this website as there is no use of such Q&A material. Better get started with proper trouble-shooting.

Comment: I tried trouble-shooting it, but the error code I received was outside of my understanding, which is why I came to this site for help. The question was as detailed as I could have given it by representing my code, the error I received and the goal of my code. By saying, `check your code` you do not help or resolve the problem. I know I can become better at trouble-shooting, but not everyone knows everything spot-on from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things that you need to change

**Frist**

Replace

```
example.com/users/username goes here/test.png
```

with

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/users/username goes here/test.png'
```

**Second**

Make sure destination folder exists (if not create it before moving
it)

if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/users/username goes here/')) {
    mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/users/username goes here/');
}

**Third**

Provide necessary permissions to write on the destination folder.

```
chmod 777 /var/www/users/
```

should work if you are on a Linux based server

Comment: Thank you for this, helped to understand the code and follow it through!

Comment: @Fasilkk solved it, but this helped me understand the order of the code.

Comment: Alright! I didn't notice that some other answer had been already accepted.

Comment: No problem, thank you though! This will help for future reference for others aswell :)